# How to compress .pdfs in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, compression

I am trying to send my cover letter and resume away but apparently it is too big to send through craigs list(my computer says the total size is 500kb) as it has a 600kb limit(so small should be at least a meg).

> Hi there. You recently tried to email
>   Some job Email, an anonymous
>   craigslist address. However, your
>   message was too big to be sent through
>   our system.
>
> Craigslist has a 600KB limit on the
>   messages we'll send. Please reduce the
>   size of your mail and try again.
>
> Thanks for using craigslist.

So when I convert my word 2007(.docx) files to pdf they become huge. Like they got from 32kb to 320kb. So is there a way I can either get around craigslist limits or compress my pdfs a bit to make it happy.

I don't want to send zips and stuff since the person who gets it might not even know what to do.

I rather not send .docx since not sure if will have office 2007 or the compatibility view installed and I rather just send it as pdf(as some place require it anyways to be in pdfs).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/), [pdfcreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), [pdf995](http://www.pdf995.com/download.html) or another pdf printer. Word 2007's "Save as PDF or XPS" has some huge memory leaks and creates very large files.

By further tweaking the settings on the pdf printers you can further reduce size, but that is probably unnecessary.

Comment: I too have the same issue as the original question asker.  Do you have any links/references for the memory leak issue in Word 2007's "Save as PDF or XPS"?   Is there an update/fix from MS for this?  Is Word 2010 also affected in the same way?

Comment: The issue is the same up to Office 2013, see my comment on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/366073/why-does-word-2010-create-such-huge-pdf-files#comment950686_366073 . My problem with using a pdf printer is that they don't keep the links inside the document (and probably other type of formatting).